# Syntax for a random effect in an R regression - not sure if nested, and how to express?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, ordered-logit, nested-data, intercept

I am running an ordinal regression for an experiment I have conducted, where the DV is ratings on a 5-point scale, and the predictors are the type of item, the type of participant (native speaker/L2/heritage) and the task (there were two tasks, both targeting the same type of linguistic phenomenon). I want to add random effects for participant and for item. I added an intercept for item `(1|item)`.

The problem: How to add the random effect for participant?
There were different lists in the experiment, meaning - every participant only saw a subset of all items, no participant saw all items. I feel that this means that I cannot just add an intercept for participant, but have to somehow use different syntax to reflect the fact that each participant only saw a subset of the items.

There isn't a column/variable for the list number, so I cannot use participant as a variable nested in that.

How should I add a participant random effect?

Comment: Could you make each combination of items that the individuals were exposed to as a factor, e.g. "A+B+C", "A+C", and then use that factor as a random effect?

Comment: I can do that. How should I phrase that random effect, then? Would it be  (1+item|combination)?

Comment: or maybe it should be (1|participant:combination)?

Comment: I believe they should be separate, e.g. `y ~ (1|combination) + (1|id) + item`. However, it depends on your experimental setup and hypothesis.

Comment: thanks, I did decide on doing that, what you proposed above